# How to scroll GridView views without using scroll bar in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have a GridView which contains 'n' items. I want to scroll our grid view without using scroll bar

```
  GridView{    
         id:product_grid     
        //width:1265     //height:621    
         boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds     
        flow:GridView.LeftToRight     
        snapMode: GridView.SnapOneRow     
        displaced: Transition{         
                   NumberAnimation{properties: "y,x"; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad }    
     }
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: I use snapMode property of GridView for scrolling the view when an item is dragged. But its not woking

Comment: Did you try [GridView.positionViewAtIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#positionViewAtIndex-method)?

Comment: Yes i tried but din work

Comment: Ok, you have to post all relevant code, Please read how to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise your code couldn't be run and test.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and fiddling, I was able to reduce it to two steps.

(1) Add `import QtQuick.Controls 2.4` at the top of the file, among your other import commands.

(2) Add `ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { visible: false }` to your `GridView` object.

Basically, you're overloading the scrollbar with a [your] custom scrollbar and make it invisible.

Here is an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4  // important

// ...

GridView {
    /* Your code
    id: product_grid
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds     
    flow: GridView.LeftToRight     
    snapMode: GridView.SnapOneRow     
    displaced: Transition {         
        NumberAnimation { properties: "y,x"; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad }
    }
    */

    // magic (overloads vertical scrollbar, allowing for customisable scrollbars)
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        visible: false    // hides scrollbar
    }

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { letter: 'a' }
        ListElement { letter: 'b' }
        ListElement { letter: 'c' }
        ListElement { letter: 'd' }
        ListElement { letter: 'e' }
        ListElement { letter: 'f' }
        ListElement { letter: 'g' }
        ListElement { letter: 'h' }
        ListElement { letter: 'i' }
        ListElement { letter: 'j' }
    }

    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 300
    height: 200

    delegate: Column {
        Text {
            color: "white"
            text: letter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
    }

}
```

Read more:

- [GridView QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html)
- [Scrollbar QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html)